# Microsoft Edge complaining about inline style with CSP but there is none

Tags: microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

After turning on CSP headers using

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com"`
```

in Apache, all browsers display my page fine except Microsoft Edge that no longer renders the HTML5 `meter` element correctly and displays lots of `CSP14312` errors in the console telling me that the `style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com` directive in the CSP header was violated by `inline style` even though I have no inline style on the page.

Unfortunately, I cannot see where exactly the violation occurs. My page uses Google Fonts (remote) and I also have Font Awesome stored locally on the server. If someone is willing to have a look, https://smares.de/ is the URL.

Do you have any idea what Edge's problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I started deleting line-by-line and for some weird reason, Edge doesn't seem to like the HTML5 `meter` element. If I remove the `meter` element, it stops complaining. It also issues one warning for `<meter...>` and one warning for `</meter>`.

Comment: That’s odd. Edge 13 and 14 are supposed to have support for `meter`. See http://caniuse.com/#search=meter. Please consider reporting an Edge bug at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/new/ And if you do please also post the bug number here too.

Comment: I posed the problem https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10050890/